# count in update statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, sql-update, sql-server-2014

I have Time table with column `AmountDayOfMonth` where values is `NULL`.
I need to update this column and insert count of days for every month.
Here is my update only for February:

```
 update [Mart].[dbo].[Time]
 set AmountDayOfMonth = (
     select (count(theMonth)) as kol1 
     from [Mart].[dbo].[Time] as t1 
     where t1.NameMonth = 'February' group by t1.TheYear
 )
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. can you edit your question to contain some sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the question, but I guess you have some calendar table with a column representing the total count of days in month. You will need only the second part. Just change table and column names to appropriate values.

Data initialization:

```
DECLARE @Time TABLE
    (
      TheYear INT ,
      MonthNumber VARCHAR(MAX) ,
      DayNumber INT ,
      AmountDayOfMonth INT
    );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   CAST('20160101' AS DATE) AS dt
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   DATEADD(dd, 1, dt)
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    DATEADD(dd, 1, dt) < '20170101'
             )
    INSERT  INTO @Time
            ( TheYear ,
              MonthNumber ,
              DayNumber
            )
            SELECT  YEAR(dt) ,
                    MONTH(dt) ,
                    DAY(dt)
            FROM    cte
    OPTION  ( MAXRECURSION 0 );
```

Update statement you need:

```
WITH    upd
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY TheYear, MonthNumber ) AS cnt
               FROM     @Time
             )
    UPDATE  upd
    SET     AmountDayOfMonth = cnt
SELECT  *
FROM    @Time
```